# Is it possible to attach PDF files to a blockchain payload?

Tags: blockchain

I have been working with blockchain for a while. The payload of a typical blockchain block may contain text. Is it at all possible for a blockchain payload to have a PDF document attached to it?

Comment: You could attach the hash of the PDF

Comment: @SebastianWalla Hello Sabastian. Thanks for the clue. Could you point me to a source code\link where something like this is done? Thanks!

Comment: https://21.co/learn/embedding-data-blockchain-op-return/#storing-a-message-in-the-blockchain-with-op_return